# Incorrect mirror after applying mirror modifier

Tags: mirror-modifier

[image]

As shown in the image, I am at -Y viewpoint, and I am creating a mirrored model about x axis. Therefore, no matter where my origin is, the image should looks be exactly the same as original object in current viewpoint.

However, it actually looks like this:
[image]

In which I need to rotate the viewport a bit to see symmetry. This is not correct. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you applied the rotation of the object (Ctrl+A > Apply > Rotation)? The mirror works on local axis, not world axis.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann That's great! Thank you.